# I have a problem with npm init, why does nothing happen in the terminal?

Tags: javascript, macos, npm, terminal, visual-studio-code

I have an issue that for any command I write in the terminal nothing happens, only the square moves to the next line!

Example: when I type `npm init` nothing happens...
I'm working on mac and vscode.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using proxy network.

Comment: fixed some grammar

Comment: If *any* command you type does nothing, then you probably aren't typing it at a command prompt. There isn't enough information to tell what you are typing it at.